# ggplot: Why is it so hard to add geom_contour to a calender heatmap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a calendar heatmap with ggplot. I found [this](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/charting-time-series-as-calendar-heat-maps-in-r.html) and [that](http://www.ggplot2-exts.org/ggTimeSeries.html), however I do not want to introduce that many dependencies as my final shiny server is limited. This is my intended result:

[image]

I'm almost done using a few lines of tidyverse code, however I struggle with the final bit, namely, highlighting months in a calendar heatmap. This is how to reproduce my issue, using my data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Load data
logdata <- read_csv("https://georoen.github.io/heuteZensiert/Logfile.csv") %>% 
  select(date:prozent) %>% 
  transmute(date = as.Date(date),
        sender = factor(ifelse(grepl("h", sendung), "ZDF", "ARD")),
        sendung = factor(sendung, labels = c("Heute 19Uhr", "Heute Journal",
                                             "Tageschau", "Tagesthemen")),
        prozent = as.numeric(gsub("%", "", prozent))) %>% 
  mutate(Day = lubridate::wday(date, label = T, abbr = F, week_start = 1),
     Day = forcats::fct_rev(Day),
     Week = lubridate::week(date),
     Month = lubridate::month(date),
     Year = lubridate::year(date)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(date))

# Plot
ggplot(logdata, aes(Week, Day)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = prozent)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = Month), binwidth = 1) +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "lightgreen", high = "red") +
  facet_grid(sendung ~ Year, scales = "free_x") +
  labs(x = "Kalenderwoche", y = "")
```

This gives me some errors due `geom_contour(aes(z = Month), binwidth = 1)` and this result:

[image]

So now I wounder why `geom_contour` does not work for outlining the months? If I put `z = Month`, isn't it the same as in this ggplot example*?
(*slightly modified by adding `geom_tile`)

```
?geom_contour()
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = density)) + geom_contour()
```

[image]

Can anyone explain what `stat_contour` is doing or why it is not possible to let `z = Month`?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Try `geom_contour(aes(y = as.numeric(Day), z = Month), binwidth = 1)`. This will, however, result in other errors. Ultimately, I'm not sure if `geom_contour` will give you the effect you want.

Comment: Thank you very much @WeihuangWong. However does not work as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c94yN.png

Comment: I think geom_contour expect x and y to be continuous, so try converting day to a numeric, and setting the y-labels with scale_y_continuous

Comment: @Jeremy: Yes, that's what I mean when I say I'm not sure if geom_contour will give you the effect you want. Perhaps look at https://github.com/AtherEnergy/ggTimeSeries/blob/a1a0dbade4cc520ae5765b22208ffd6847c28e55/R/ggplot_calendar_heatmap.R#L138 and the rows that follow to see how you could draw the vertical and horizontal dividing line segments individually.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think it really is, that both geoms are not compatible. geom_tile() draws rectangles around point data - geom_contour connects point data. Therefor it is not possible to draw a contour around the tiles. I started drawing the edges by preparing a second data frame in advance now. You can stay tuned https://github.com/georoen/heuteZensiert/blob/master/app_heatmap.R :-)